# PSA: Quantal is now off topic

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, cleanup

Yeah, that time again, we will have from here on each 6 months new EOL announcements so, here the general plan for questions:

- New questions about Quantal 12.10 that only affect Quantal (e.g., APT dependencies, hardware, login, quirks, etc. issues) are off topic. Ask the OP if they can reproduce the same behavior on non-EOL like Precise, Saucy or Trusty.
- Old questions that have no good answer (ie, answers that you would downvote, or that do not apply to OP's problem, or are guesses) and only affect Quantal should get closed. Note, there are questions about Quantal that are very generic, for those, just remove the references to the version of Ubuntu (tag, title and body) clean up and maybe attach a bounty ;).
- Old questions with good answers should remain open. Just remove any references to the version in the question itself.
- Bugs are to be closed, just close them. No special treatment here.

Comment: I agree with almost all of this, I just see no reason to go digging through old posts editing things. If it has a reasonable answer and/or is accepted just let it be.

Comment: @Seth you are saying exactly the opposite of what I'm saying. I'm saying that if it's a generic problem, we should remove all references to the version of Ubuntu (point 3).

Comment: Oh, in that case I agree with you. I thought you meant go through and remove all version information from all of them.

Comment: @Seth if the question is generic, I would, even if it isn't EOL yet.

Answer (score 5):

> - Old questions with good answers should remain open. Just remove any references to the version in the question itself.

Why remove version information? If a question has an answer and the release is since EOL'd just leave it alone.

> - Old questions that have no good answer...

This seems highly subjective. If the question has an answer leave it be.

Comment: Why not improve something? The version information is most of the time noise for the generic questions, and irrelevant noise is subject of removal. It also prevents duplicates since people will not ask the same question again and again for each version of Ubuntu. We do not need a question about how ping a host for each version of Ubuntu. Related http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9026/169736