# The wording of OT/bug in the Close Votes Review queue seems ambiguius

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The close reason states

> Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

related: [Let's refine and clarify our off-topic close reasons](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12160/lets-refine-and-clarify-our-off-topic-close-reasons)

This is fine in regard of bug reports for Ubuntu but not so for other bugs, e.g. [Dependencies on simple scan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937977/dependencies-on-simple-scan)

This question should be closed as OT because it is a bug report, but the pointer to Launchpad is useless in this case. Should we amend the close reason to cater for bug outside of the immediate Ubuntu eco system?

Comment: That question seems to be more "how do I contact the maintainer" which would seem to be on-topic.  The close reasons have rather strict character limits, which might be why the wording is so brief here. I'll have to see how much remaining space we have. My first question would be what resource do you want to link to? There's hardly a single place to report bugs.

Comment: @Seth my idea was to add "... reported to the maintainer or on launchpad..." (or so)