# A note on flagging end of life questions

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

Recently in review, there seems to be a lot of questions flagged for `end of life`, the issue with these flags is that when the questions were written they were ON TOPIC, this is important, old questions are not removed once a release goes EOL.

Please, please, please read the date a question was posted BEFORE you flag it as end of life, if it was on topic when it was asked it is still on topic now, context is very important here.

[See this example](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/519249), it was written on `Feb 5 '12 at 13:25` and is about `11.10` so it is on topic in the context of when it was written, so it stays and should not be flagged.

Sorry if this seem a bit of a rant but is is very frustrating to have to review these flags when the information is right there on the page, just look above the posters user name, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Good one, and easy to mistake if someone edits such a post, and it pops up to the front page.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will help a little, in cleaning up the queue :)

Comment: Someone flags all post with `freeze` tag. Yhis is not the first time when we get lot's of this kind of flags. It will be good if some of the mods talk to the person who flags.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have not noticed that one, I will look out for it, I have notice a lot of other `off topic` flags in a similar vain though ie Just flagging questions they don't like a `off topic`, I totally agree, we need mods to intervene in the close votes queue, it is out of control and getting worse, it is very hard for us normal users to do anything as (to me at least, could be different for you @10k+) flags are anonymous.

Comment: I (nearly) fell into this trap several times - mostly because of the weird way dates are displayed - but the quest for a sane international date format on SE is still on :-))

Comment: @guntbert Is there a proposal I can vote on? That would help a lot.

Comment: @markkirby https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218561/can-we-have-a-user-preference-for-iso-standard-date-format-for-all-dates-times

Answer (score 17):

Good reminder, Mark.

The question in question here however ended up in the review queue because somebody directly close-voted it as:

> off-topic → This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

I won't name them here but they're weren't otherwise involved in the review. I find this approach fairly tedious and incredibly labour-intensive for something that wasn't bothering anybody else. **Just leave old stuff alone*.** There will simply *always* be too many old posts to handle it like this.

But maybe they had a reason. I'll poke them towards this thread if they haven't already seen it and if they want to leave a reply, they can.

<sub>* Unless you want to improve it and make it apply to new situations, which we're more than happy for people to do!</sub>

Comment: true oli. But yes, excellent point bringing this to the table about flagging and real EOL questions.

Comment: Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 3):

So, I was mailed about this. I'm not happy. In fact, [I knew it wasn't anything good](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28466566#28466566).

**I** was the one that voted to close that question as **not reproducible**, and I would do it again. The question has been asked *3 years ago*, it isn't viewed by anyone (which is a metric some people love to use), and the answer is another regurgitation of "buy a better system or use something more light" which we don't lack.

**These kind of Q&A's aren't useful since it drops the general quality of the site** and, since we are in the process of burning the [freeze tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14878/169736), I took up the task. This tag needs to be removed *someday*, we discussed this several occasions. I'm more mindful about the inaction around this kind of issues, since the [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) **reduce the visibility of questions**, as is normally the only tag used or used with other problematic tags (like [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash)) that is like shooting ourself in the foot.

Everything has been done while being mindful of Shog's [**"When to burninate"**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575) guidance, specifically the *"Start by cleaning up the edges"* section, since the other procedure has already been completed.

**This is not me mindlessly voting to close questions I don't like.** You can check my review history and you will find some examples that I [redeemed](https://askubuntu.com/posts/295013/revisions) of questions badly tagged. I would ask instead turn this meta post in a plea for help, since when I [hinted of my actions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=26872633#26872633) hopping a good kind soul would take up the challenge with me, nobody offered a hand, and I even found evidence of [people going against this](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/519320), since closing as duplicated wouldn't help to remove the tag.

I'm not even sure why the reviewers through it was EOL, and I'm kind of disappointed because I always have said ["remove the references to the version of Ubuntu"](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9118/169736) to evaluate if a question is factually EOL. I'm not sure of the others EOL questions that you might be seeing. It would help if you show more examples to help you with your issue.

Comment: I think this answer just shows you are in the wrong. The Mods don't want you to do this, and the community doesn't. I'd suggest you drop it.

Comment: @Tim on what arguments you imply the community is against?

Comment: Well literally nobody wants to...

Comment: @Tim again I'm not seeing any outcry, care to share?

Comment: @Braiam thanks for replying, I think in my question I could of given a better example of my issue, I will look for a better one in review tomorrow, I don't have an issue with you closing questions you think should be closed, I was expecting this to be a low rep user who made a mistake, but I guess not. First, I am not against removal of the tag in question or you cleaning up the site. After reading your links and some other questions on meta where people have had an experience like I had in the queue, I think this may be more of an indication of a larger problem with removing questions works.

Comment: Mainly I think it is an issue with a lack of clear indication of what is actually going on in the review queue, ie You flag a question like this and I see it in amongst many bad flags and here we are, this seems to happen quite a lot around here, someone flags something or removes something and someone else complains. It seems to me, rather than arguing amongst our selfs we should be looking in to ways to improve removal of old questions that no longer have value. I would say sending these to the queue is inefficient, causes confusion (like this) and not to mention the size of the close queue.

Comment: To avoid this kind of thing I think we need a better solution for dealing with this type of question removal, perhaps a new queue exclusively for questions older than two years only for user with the rep to know why it is there or some kind of extra privilege to allow questions to be removed in a more simple manner than the queue, I will try my self to come up with a few more examples and an idea proposal, if you can think of a way we can deal with this without people getting confused and frustrated, please put it forward, you, of course, have my support in cleaning up but we need to come up

Comment: with a way of dealing with it that will stop this type of situation arising.

Comment: @markkirby wow, many statements. Lets see if I can answer them in order. 1) When you see a number besides a close reason, is a fellow 3ker close vote, not a flag. fFlag/flag count aren't visible to us. 2) SE gave us lemons, we try to make lemonade. There have been several attempts to make easier to remove tags The Right Way™, this is the best we currently have available. Remember, you are seeing just a half of my actions, since I can single-handedly allow a question to be deleted, clearing the tag. 3) Again, I'm not removing old questions, but cleaning a tag with bad questions. (cont.)

Comment: Bad questions needs to be removed somehow. The tools available only allow us to close them and if they have no upvoted posts it's deleted 9 days later. This is what we can do right now, if you have an specific idea, [you may find participate here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077) to get some ideas down the pipe. 4) The bigger frustration that I have is that there are not reviewers reviewing things. We have enough users with +3k to clear the queue in days and keep it like that. I suggest that your next post is asking instead for people to come forward and curate content.

Comment: If content is not curated the site quality will only get worse.