# EOL Notice: Wily Werewolf (15.10) is now End of Life (as of July 28, 2016) (Enforcement starts July 29)

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

> This will be enforced starting on July 29, 2016.

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that have reached End of Life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives are **officially end of life** as of July 28, 2016:

- Wily Werewolf (15.10).

New questions regarding the above posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**. Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed via the **[15.10 End of Life Announcement email message stating the official End Of Life date](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2016-July/003492.html)**, establishing July 28th, 2016 as the EOL date for Wily.

Please upgrade to a supported release to continue to receive support via Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Security updates. If you don't like upgrading every 9 months, it is highly recommended you install a [long term support release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) in the future.

---

> This Meta thread is NOT a discussion of how we handle EOL releases. This is simply a notification to all about an upcoming "End of Life" date for a current release of Ubuntu (as of this posting being made). Please refrain from asking in comments about how we handle EOL questions, or commenting on such handling policies.

Relevant related posts:

- [A note on flagging End of Life questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14993/a-note-on-flagging-end-of-life-questions)
- [Should we allow questions that are about releases which are considered End of Life?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li)
- [EOL Question Handling Discussion... again](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again)

Comment: _Takes off hat in respect of Wily's passing._

Comment: RIP willy werewolf, looks like the werewolf is dying from age...

Comment: @Edity Please. It's "wily". Yours means something else.

Comment: "may need to be considered off-topic." -> may need or will?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt "May" - there are a few cases where questions regarding 15.10 after EOL may not be 'offtopic' (such as "How do I upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04" or such, though they'll just get marked as dupes of the how to upgrade questions that already exist heh).  After having done a bunch of these EOL notices it's been refined to let a *little bit* of give exist, but not so much that it's insanely broad.

Comment: hats off, man. ]\

Comment: TOMMOROW- ubuntu 15.10 RIP

Comment: So I have to burn another Ubuntu DVD? .......what a fun time to be had.

Comment: @SahibPrime No you don't, USB drives are dirt-cheap. :)

Comment: 15.10 IS NOW R.I.P

Comment: 15.10 dead. But now only LTS versions supported!

Comment: @ubashu In less than 4 months, a new release should be out (16.10)!

Comment: Yep but for now only LTS.

Comment: Could we please change the title to "A silver bullet has come for the Wily Werewolf"?

Comment: This is about Wily Werewolf. As announced [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15739/eol-notice-wily-werewolf-15-10-is-now-end-of-life-as-of-july-28-2016-enfo) this is now off-topic.

Answer (score 12):

For those who would rather not upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 for whatever reason such as a lack of support for AMD's old fglrx driver, note that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will still be officially supported until April 2019, according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Ubuntu 16.04 does have advantages over 14.04, such as an updated Linux kernel that provides better hardware support. The wireless card in my laptop had strange problems until upgrading to Mint 18. Ubuntu 16.04 also requires less updates after installation and will have greater support for software in the future. For example, Ubuntu 12.04 is supposed to be supported until April 2017, but a lot of newer software only seems to have instructions or official PPAs for 14.04+.

Comment: Why downgrade to 14.04?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος If possible, the upgrade to 16.04 would be better, but there are a few reasons why 14.04 may be the only option. For example, AMD's fglrx driver is now unsupported and will not come to 16.04, and the drivers AMD made to replace it are only for their newest cards, forcing users to use the open source drivers. While this isn't necessarily bad, sometimes this can cause problems with certain games and is usually behind on OpenGL versions. Also, Steam has a lot of problems when trying to use open source drivers. (Which aren't hard to fix, but are extremely annoying.)

Comment: Miss 15.10... :(

Answer (score 10):

Not all questions tagged with an out of support version are off-topic as some of these are not version specific. I recall occasions where the OP tags the question with the version they are using without realizing that the answer is the same for numerous versions (one or more of which may still be supported) Example Question:  How can I see how my drives are partitioned with Ubuntu 15.04? Example answers could include CLI solutions such as fdisk -l and GUI solutions such as gparted both of which were valid then and are still valid on supported releases. In order to help the maximum amount of users it's important to watch for mis-tagged questions where the answer is still valid for currently supported releases. In this case, remove the erroneous tag and answer as usual. Question title may also have to be changed to reflect the on-topic nature of the question. There are numerous examples on the site of questions with answers that are still valid today that may have been written for a no longer supported version. (Granted we keep those that were current when answered anyway, but you see my point.) I'm sure I'm not the only one who has removed a version tag that wasn't relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but another point is that upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu should be a troubleshooting step that comes *before* asking about the problem on this site.  It can be hard to determine what problems would not be problems anymore if the user was using a supported version.

Comment: @thomasrutter I see an example is in order. I'll modify my answer to avoid further confusion

Comment: Not all questions are troubleshooting questions.

Comment: That's true, in which case then I agree a version tag is not relevant and, as you say, can be removed or ignored.

Comment: @thomasrutter I would lean towards removal as ignoring it just leaves a stumbling block for the next person (who may or may not know) who has to decide whether it's version specific or not.