# EOL Notice: Yakkety Yak (16.10) reached End of Life on July 20, 2017

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

> This will be enforced as of July 21, 2017.

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that has reached End of Life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives **are officially end of life** as of July 20, 2017:

- Yakkety Yak (16.10)

New questions specific to the above versions posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**. Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed via the **[16.10 End of Life Announcement email message stating the official End Of Life date](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2017-July/000222.html)**, establishing July 20th, 2017 as the EOL date for Yakkety.

Please upgrade to a supported release to continue to receive support via Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Security updates.

---

> This Meta thread is NOT a discussion of how we handle EOL releases. This is simply a notification to all about an upcoming "End of Life" date for a current release of Ubuntu (as of this posting being made). Please refrain from asking in comments about how we handle EOL questions, or commenting on such handling policies.  Please also refrain from posting such things in answers on this post as well.

---

Relevant related posts:

- [A note on flagging End of Life questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14993/a-note-on-flagging-end-of-life-questions)
- [Should we allow questions that are about releases which are considered End of Life?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li)
- [EOL Question Handling Discussion... again](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again)