# Good idea to remove EOL release questions?

Tags: discussion

Like the title suggest since it has no relevance anyways, especially, the questions that don't have an accepted answer.

I think it would be great to do this for a cleaner site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already have policy on this.

[Here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li), [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14993/a-note-on-flagging-end-of-life-questions), and [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again) are the big threads related to this, mostly dealing with flagging and closure of EOL-release questions, but many of the concepts for that apply here as well; I'd highly suggest reading those because it'll give you a lot of background on how we've discussed this issue in the past (and I've been here for a lot of that discussion heh)

And no, EOL-release questions on their own should not be deleted **just** because they went EOL, because of 'historical purposes' - at the time of posting it *was* a supported release, which takes precedent (same for the flagging rules).  We don't just delete stuff because it's old either.  We *do* delete things under certain criterion for "old" automatically, but EOL releases being the primary subject isn't one of those criterion.

Also, "old" answers to EOL release items can *still* be helpful even today in 16.04 and later.  (case in point, some 9.04 answers with CLI-based approaches to dealing with an issue can *still work* in 16.04, and even older "manage partitions and such on the command line" answers can still work too though with some tweaking.)

Comment: True.  Then should we just close them?

Comment: @MathCubes Again read the links I gave you for guidance on closing those questions.  Everything is discussed and explained in those links.