# EOL Notice: Artful Aardvark (17.10) reached End of Life on July 19, 2018

Tags: discussion, end-of-life

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that will be reaching End of Life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives **are officially past end of life** as of July 19, 2018:

- Artful Aardvark (17.10)

New questions specific to the above versions posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**. Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed via the **[17.10 End of Life Announcement email message stating the official End Of Life date](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000232.html)**, establishing July 19th, 2018 as the EOL date for Artful.  The official declaration of 17.10 now becoming End of Life can be confirmed at [the relevant announcement email sent on July 19, 2018 at 22:47 UTC](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000233.html).

Please upgrade to a supported release to continue to receive support via Ask Ubuntu and Ubuntu Security updates.

---

> This Meta thread is NOT a discussion of how we handle EOL releases. This is simply a notification to all about an upcoming "End of Life" date for a current release of Ubuntu (as of this posting being made). Please refrain from asking in comments about how we handle EOL questions, or commenting on such handling policies.  Please also refrain from posting such things in answers on this post as well.

---

Relevant related posts:

- [A note on flagging End of Life questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14993/a-note-on-flagging-end-of-life-questions)
- [Should we allow questions that are about releases which are considered End of Life?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li)
- [EOL Question Handling Discussion... again](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7457/eol-question-handling-discussion-again)